# GWT: is there a way to modify Cast.java file the Gwt uses in compilation?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I tried to place the file under com.google.gwt.lang but it still uses the old implementation in compilation instead of my modified implementation.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://code.google.com/searchframe#T04cSGC7sWI/trunk/dev/core/super/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/intrinsic/Intrinsic.gwt.xml

```
<!-- Fundamental types required by code generation and other basics.        -->
<!-- Do not inherit this module directly; inherit com.google.gwt.core.Core. -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Types from this module are not visible to nor imported into user code. -->
<!--                                                                        -->
```

If you really need changes here I would suggest to rebuild the gwt-dev.jar from sources and put it on the classpath instead of the current one:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/makinggwtbetter#compiling